# changing global variables in NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've defined these global variables but I cant seem to change their value in the code. I need other C modules to have access to these variables.

```
global base 
global freep 

SECTION .data  
  base:   dd   0           
  freep:     dd    0
```

The code below gives this error:

:173: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

So my question is how to a mov values into global variables?

```
  mov freep, esi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2):

> **2.2.2 NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References**
> The rule is simply that any access to the contents of a memory location requires square brackets around the address, and any access to the address of a variable doesn't.

So if you want to store the value of `esi` at `freep` you should write:

```
mov [freep], esi
```

And if you wanted to get `freep`'s address and put it in `esi` you would've written:

```
mov esi, freep
```

The instruction `mov freep, esi` is invalid, because `freep` here is an immediate (the address of `freep`), and you can't have an immediate as a destination operand.

Comment: thanks alot, if one wanted the value of freep at esi, would it be mov esi, [freep]

Comment: I have one last question, my global variable is a struct with member size and ptr. 
How would I address members size and ptr? would it be [freep + 4] for ptr and [freep + 8] for size?

Comment: See [section 4.12.10](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.10) in the manual for how you can declare and use structures in NASM assembly.