# to print to console --> ambuiguity for contents in ecx and edx registers

Tags: assembly, nasm, inline-assembly

from my previous doubt - [Difference between “mov eax, [num]” and “mov eax, num”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463649/difference-between-mov-eax-num-and-mov-eax-num)

I came to know " mov eax, num " will store **address of num** in eax and " mov eax, [num] " will store **value of num** in eax

Now HERE !

```
    mov     edx, strLen     ; Arg three: the length of the string
    mov     ecx, str        ; Arg two: the address of the string
    mov     ebx, 1          ; Arg one: file descriptor, in this case stdout
    mov     eax, 4          ; Syscall number, in this case the write(2)  

    int     0x80            ; Interrupt 0x80   

section .data     
    str:     db 'Hello, world!',0xA
    strLen:  equ $-str
```

Ideally edx register should have length, so

- as " **mov ecx, str** " - stores **address of str** in ecx
- haven't " **mov edx, strlen** " should also store address of strlen and not the value in edx.
- to store **value of strlen** in edx, why are we not using " **mov edx, [strlen]** "

the following code is referenced from this link - http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html

Its killing me !

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: is the declaration in section .data and not in section .bss has any relevance to my question ! 
PS : I know section .data, is for declaring constants and section .bss,  is for declaring variables.

Comment: *"mov eax, [num] " will store value **of** num in eax"* is probably more accurately stated as, *"mov eax, [num] " will store value **at** num in eax"*, which is probably what you meant.

Comment: @lurker yes Lurker thats what I meant

Answer (score 1):

`strLen` is an *equate* (`strLen:  equ $-str`). So what's happening is just compile-time textual substitution from `mov edx, strLen` to `mov edx, 14`.

Using brackets here would be incorrect, because that would give you `mov edx, [14]`, which isn't what you want to do.

(see section 3.2.4 EQU: Defining Constants in the NASM manual)

Comment: @Micheal
hey Micheal thanks for this but how about following ! 
"file_name" below is not an equate


section .data


**file_name  db  'myfile.txt'**

section .text

mov eax, 8

mov ebx, **file_name**

mov ecx, 0777

int 0x80

Comment: There you're loading the address of `file_name`, as the question you linked to explained.